# is there a way to dynamically put a spinner next to a control instead of having divs all over the place

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, getjson, spinner

i have a number of dropdown controls and on the change event it kicks off ajax getJSON() calls.  I have a div next to each dropdown with a spinner image as i want to display "loading . . " as some of the ajax calls are expensive.

Is there anyway i can just have one spinner div on the page and have the spinner move right next to the dropdown control that i just changed at that point. this way i can reuse one div instead of having them over and over on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a spinner, or move it.  It's easier to just destroy and create one on the ajax request I think...I have something like this when calling to a webservice to get something.

```
$(document.createElement("img"))
  .attr({ "src": "/Ajax/Spinner.gif" })
  .insertAfter(dropDownElementThatWasJustClicked);
```

In my case, I'm destroying everything inside that parent and replacing it when I get data back, so it destroys the spinner as part of that.

Comment: i tried that but i dont see the image showing... do you need to add any additional line to have the image show or should .appendTo do it by itself.  I am calling .appendTo on the id of the dropdown.  is this correct?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, noticed on a re-read that .insertAfter() matched your situation much better, glad it's working now.

Comment: what is the difference between insertafter() and appendto() ?? They sound the same

Comment: .AppendTo() say on a div, would stick it inside the div as the last element, .insertAfter() sticks it after the div element, as the next sibling.  Here's the full list of manipulations with short descriptions: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation